# Cannot click on contanct elements in whatsapp web using click() function

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, whatsapp

I was trying to make a WhatsApp chatbot extension. I want to read every unread message and send those contacts some messages. I chose web scraping due to the limitations of whatsapp API and its cost. This is the command I use to click on web elements. For selecting contacts I made the function

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('div[class="lhggkp7q ln8gz9je rx9719la"]') //for listing all contacts on the screen
list[0].click()//just clicking a contact of my choice for experimental purpose
```

but unfortunately, the contact is not being selected so I can't proceed to setting a message and sending it. Is there any way to simulate a click or something? Or am I selecting the wrong element, so the click event is not defined for it?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do it.
You can't do that. You need to buy whatsapp API. Or go for telegram it's free.